# gitconfig file in unexpected location

Tags: git, bash, command-line, terminal

I tried to set a git alias like so:

`git config --global alias.co checkout`

but I get the following error:

```
error: could not lock config file /Users/[username]/.gitconfig: No such file or directory
```

When I `ls -a` I see `.gitconfig` does exist.

After digging around some more I noticed a `config` file within `~/.git`. Opening this file revealed the following git settings:

```
[core]
      repositoryformatversion = 0
      filemode = true
      bare = false
      logallrefupdates = true
      ignorecase = true
      precomposeunicode = false
[user]
      name = [My Name]
      email = [my email address]
```

Should this be where I place my git settings such as aliases? Also, why do settings seem to reside here rather than `.gitconfig`?

Answer (score 0):

First, do a git config -l --show-origin: that will list all config settings considered by git for your (system,global,local) settings.

Second, check your `$HOME` value and your current id: does the current user can aven do an `ls /Users/[username]`? Your message looks more than a right access issue.

Third, the `~/.git/config` is the local config of a git repo done at `~` (right next where your global git config should be).
I suggest to move that `.git` folder elsewhere and see if the issue persists, as you might not want your all `$HOME` to be one giant git repo.